# Read multipart response

Tags: okhttp

there are documentations on how to send a multipart message but no information I can find relates to how to receive a multipart message.

I have a restful service that returns multiple files in a multipart message. I wonder what is the best way to use OKHttp to handle the response.  Ideally, I can use MOSHI only.

Many thanks,
Jason

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at [MultipartBody.Builder](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/MultipartBody.Builder.html) and [the multipart recipe](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#posting-a-multipart-request).

Comment: Jesse, thanks but thats the 'documentation on how to send a multipart message' I mentioned in the question. The MultipartBody code clearly only does the building of the message not the parsing. Thanks

Comment: My bad. No multipart decoder in OkHttp yet. Someday. There’s probably an open source project that’ll do it but you’ll need to depend on 2 new logging libraries.